# Cloudbees Clickstarts are breaking for me

Tags: cloudbees

When starting any of the clickstarts i'm getting the following response:

404 Not Found

## Not Found

The requested URL /accounts/my-account/repos was not found on this server.

---

Apache Server at api.forge.cloudbees.com Port 80

anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gertjan,

This was caused by an internal misconfiguration that has now been corrected.

Can you please try again.

Comment: Confirmed, I can now use clickstarts :)